# Who can I complain to about MS Product activation service

Tags: activation

Ok, I'm fuming after having to deal with a MS Support Rep to do a product activation; and now I need to complain to someone.

Has anyone found an actual phone number or e-mail address at Microsoft I can complain too?
All I can find is their support pages and the feed back forms for specific support pages.

Comment: I figure if that PC-bimbo on the Windows 7 ad can convince MS to build Windows 7 for her, they must be able to straighten out their support people for me :-/

Comment: This is a) not sysadmin related b) not a real question c) should be CW

Comment: a) When I'm having problems activating the OS on a server, it is SA related b) definitely real, c) It would be CW only if I was looking for discussion... I was looking for a fact.

Comment: Is it the fact that you had to deal with somebody to do the activation, or something that happened over the course of the call that has you fuming?  If the former, I'm sorry but the answer is "live with it".  If the latter, the person's manager will soon catch them giving bad customer service (yes, MS *do* care about customer service) and the inevitable consequences will follow.  Either way, voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"We're Microsoft.  We don't have to care."

Comment: Wasn't that Bell's line?

Comment: I think the parallels are pretty clear...

Answer (score 3):

Call back into the Activation number, and punch in a bunch of bogus numbers to get to a person (or just sit there and ignore the prompts).  When a person comes on the line, tell them that you have an issue you need to speak with a supervisor about.  Unfortunately without the name of the person there's probably not much they can do, but you can vent to them, and they can and will send it up the chain.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make your complaints really heard is the get involved in the MS blogging and beta testing community.  I truly believe this is the only real way of getting your voice heard by the actual developers of the software.

Calling/Email "Bob" in Mumbai isn't going to go anywhere.

Comment: Actually, it's "Bob" in Mumbai that is the problem.

Comment: And his boss likely also lives there...

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of their Customer Service Solution Centers:

http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/cu_inventory?ws=mscom

But it's probably analogous to shouting into the wind or relieving yourself in the ocean.

Comment: been there... no phone number or e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely to get anything changed.  If you talk to an unhelpful support person, best thing is simply to hang up and try someone else.  If they mention it then you can always say that you were cut off.